# Why won't BaseOutputPath resolve in this AfterBuild target?

Tags: properties, msbuild

This is a simple batch file that performs a copy to

\bin\DEBUG or \bin\RELEASE -

and it cleans up some garbage that the nuget libraries drag along.

But, this property $([BaseOutputPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx)) resolves to a blank.

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <!-- $(BaseOutputPath)\$(Configuration)\. doesn't work! -->
  <Exec Command="CALL postbuild.bat bin\$(Configuration)\" />
</Target>
```

So 2 questions:

1. What is the correct "property" to use?
2. How should this property be escaped correctly?

Comment: `$(BaseOutputPath)` is the correct syntax, but the docs say '*if* it is set` which might mean that if you don't set it anywhere, it's just not there (and that matches with your observations). I assume this is a C# project, so I'd go for `$(OutputPath)` which normally already includes $(Configuration) and $(Platform).

Comment: That's an answer! move that comment to answer so I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation on BaseOutputPath states '*If* it is set, MSBuild will use OutputPath = $(BaseOutputPath)\$(Configuration)\' so in other words: if you do not set it in the project file (manually, there is no VS gui entry for it) it is simply not defined. Weirdly enough if I search all files in the MsBuild program files' directory, there is no BaseOutputPath anywhere to be found. So maybe it's only used for project types I don't have installed or it's somewhere else (no idea where that would be). Mysterious but I don't have the time now to figure it out. The Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets has intersting info though, and your answer:

```
OutDir:
Indicates the final output location for the project or solution. When building a solution,
OutDir can be used to gather multiple project outputs in one location. In addition,
OutDir is included in AssemblySearchPaths used for resolving references.

OutputPath:
This property is usually specified in the project file and is used to initialize OutDir.
OutDir and OutputPath are distinguished for legacy reasons, and OutDir should be used if at all possible.

BaseIntermediateOutputPath:
This is the top level folder where all configuration specific intermediate output folders will be created.
Default value is obj\

IntermediateOutputPath:
This is the full intermediate Output Path, and is derived from BaseIntermediateOutputPath, if none specified
(eg. obj\debug). If this property is overridden, then setting BaseIntermediateOutputPath has no effect.
```

So `$(OutDir)` would be the proper choice here, or `$(outputPath)` would do it as well. By default those are set to something like `bin\$(Configuration)` so that's exactly what you want.

Comment: I see plenty of references to `BaseOutputPath` inside the VS 2019 version of `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets"`